# can't adapt type 'product.product' from v8 to v10

Tags: python, odoo-8, odoo

in odoo store there is a module called `product_pack`, it contains a file `product.py`, this file contains the function bellow in `version 8` which is made to check product availability .

so, after trying to convert it to `version 10` I got an error exactly in line 6 and line 11. so my problem is exactly in converting `res = super(product_product, self)._product_available(cr, uid, list(set(ids) - set(pack_product_ids)),field_names, arg, context)`

it raises:

> pobjs = [adapt(o) for o in self._seq]
>       ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'product.product'

- version 8

  ```
  def _product_available(self, cr, uid, ids, field_names=None, arg=False, context=None):

      pack_product_ids = self.search(cr, uid, [('pack', '=', True),
      ('id', 'in', ids),])
      res = super(product_product, self)._product_available(
          cr, uid, list(set(ids) - set(pack_product_ids)),
          field_names, arg, context)
      for product in self.browse(cr, uid, pack_product_ids, context=context):
          pack_qty_available = []
          pack_virtual_available = []
          for subproduct in product.pack_line_ids:
              subproduct_stock = self._product_available(cr, uid, [subproduct.product_id.id], field_names, arg,
                  context)[subproduct.product_id.id]
              sub_qty = subproduct.quantity
              if sub_qty:
                  pack_qty_available.append(math.floor(
                      subproduct_stock['qty_available'] / sub_qty))
                  pack_virtual_available.append(math.floor(
                      subproduct_stock['virtual_available'] / sub_qty))
          res[product.id] = {
              'qty_available': (
                  pack_qty_available and min(pack_qty_available) or False),
              'incoming_qty': 0,
              'outgoing_qty': 0,
              'virtual_available': (
                  pack_virtual_available and
                  max(min(pack_virtual_available), 0) or False),
          }
      return res
  ```
- version 10

  ```
  def _product_available(self, field_names=None, arg=False):

          pack_product_ids = self.search([('pack', '=', True)])
          ###res = super(product_product, self)._product_available(field_names, arg)
          for product in self.browse(pack_product_ids):
              pack_qty_available = []
              pack_virtual_available = []
          for subproduct in product.pack_line_ids:
              subproduct_stock = self._product_available([subproduct.product_id.id], field_names, arg)[subproduct.product_id.id]
              sub_qty = subproduct.quantity
              if sub_qty:
                  pack_qty_available.append(math.floor(subproduct_stock['qty_available'] / sub_qty))
                  pack_virtual_available.append(math.floor(subproduct_stock['virtual_available'] / sub_qty))
          res[product.id] = {
              'qty_available': (pack_qty_available and min(pack_qty_available) or False),
              'incoming_qty': 0,
              'outgoing_qty': 0,
              'virtual_available': (pack_virtual_available and max(min(pack_virtual_available), 0) or False),
          }
      return res
  ```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi,  the function that chack the availablity qty already exist in odoo10, serach in `stock/models/product.py` the function `_search_qty_available`

Comment: thank you, but what they did here is new module named product_pack , and they override the function _product_available

Comment: Make you sure the model uses is `product.produt` not `product.template`

Comment: it did work perfectly in v8, the problem here is the conversion of the method into v10 exactly in: res super(.......) and subproduct_stock = self._product_available(...)

Answer (score 0):

it did work using this one;

```
@api.multi
def _product_available(self, field_names=None, arg=False):
    pack_products = self.filtered(lambda p: p.pack == True)
    res = super(product_product, self - pack_products)._product_available(field_names, arg)

    for product in pack_products:
        pack_qty_available = []
        pack_virtual_available = []
        for pack_line in product.pack_line_ids:
            subproduct_stock = pack_line.product_id._product_available(field_names, arg)[pack_line.product_id.id]
            sub_qty = pack_line.quantity
            if sub_qty:
                pack_qty_available.append(math.floor(
                    subproduct_stock['qty_available'] / sub_qty))
                pack_virtual_available.append(math.floor(
                    subproduct_stock['virtual_available'] / sub_qty))
        # TODO calcular correctamente pack virtual available para negativos
        res[product.id] = {
            'qty_available': (
                pack_qty_available and min(pack_qty_available) or False),
            'incoming_qty': 0,
            'outgoing_qty': 0,
            'virtual_available': (
                pack_virtual_available and min(pack_virtual_available) or False),
        }
    return res
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
@api.depends('stock_quant_ids', 'stock_move_ids')
def _compute_quantities(self):
    packs = self.filtered('pack')
    no_packs = (self + packs.mapped('pack_line_ids.product_id')) - packs
    res = super(ProductProduct, no_packs)._compute_quantities()
    for product in packs:
        pack_qty_available = []
        pack_virtual_available = []
        for subproduct in product.pack_line_ids:
            subproduct_stock = res[subproduct.product_id.id]
            sub_qty = subproduct.quantity
            if sub_qty:
                pack_qty_available.append(math.floor(
                    subproduct_stock['qty_available'] / sub_qty))
                pack_virtual_available.append(math.floor(
                    subproduct_stock['virtual_available'] / sub_qty))
        # TODO calcular correctamente pack virtual available para negativos
        res[product.id] = {
            'qty_available': (
                pack_qty_available and min(pack_qty_available) or False),
            'incoming_qty': 0,
            'outgoing_qty': 0,
            'virtual_available': (
                pack_virtual_available and
                max(min(pack_virtual_available), 0) or False),
        }
    return res
```